# How to add an app bar to a Windows Phone 8 app using HTML5

Tags: javascript, windows, html, windows-phone-8, appbar

I can see how to make one in XAML or C++, but I don't know either of these languages. How do I add an app bar to my app with HTML5?

Comment: This might help you.Check and tell. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465309.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465309.aspx)

Comment: Are you using WinJS? You don't say what tech you're using.

Comment: You'll want the appbar ... I'm not sure what more to provide as you didn't provide any of your existing code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx

Comment: see this link, it's helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779534/adding-an-app-bar-in-wp8-1-html5

Answer (score 0):

This sample demonstrates how to use the app bar to present navigation, commands, and tools to users.
[HTML AppBar control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9)

Work with Win8.1 and WP8.1